# Retrieve HTTP status from Promise<JsonNode> on Play 2.3.7

Tags: java, json, playframework, promise, playframework-2.3

in our project we use JSON for data transmission between front and backend.
Basically we creating requests by preparing WSRequestHolder, just like the play doc tells to (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/JavaWS)
and then posting a json string.
The WSResponse is then mapped "asJson" returned as a Promise.

But unlike WSResponse, the JsonNode does not contain the http status returned from backend, neither does the Promise.

We need to distinguish between different status codes later on in the code for proper response handling.

So far we got a factory class which provides prepared objects, where a WSRequestHolder is held with url, header and content type set, to post the json data. Further we implemented "post" in the factory like this:

```
/**
 * Posts the given json body to the specified url
 *
 * @param body Body of JSON node to post
 * @return Promised response from post call
 */
@Override
public F.Promise<JsonNode> post(JsonNode body) {
    try {
        return wsRequestHolder.post(body).map(WSResponse::asJson).recover(new F.Function<Throwable, JsonNode>() {
            // if null response is returned, recover it and return 'java' null properly
            @Override
            public JsonNode apply(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the controllers the returned promise can then be unwrapped to retrieve the actual json response as a JsonNode.

```
F.Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise = Factory.preparedJson(url).post(someJsonNode);

JsonNode jsonResponse = jsonPromise.get(responseTimeoutInMs);
```

But yeah - somewhere in between on controller level, I need to check the status code.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Greets, Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the status response from the WSResponse object, and return it in the promise along with the JsonNode. This is a simple example:

```
Promise<Pair<JsonNode,Integer>> jsonPromise = WS.url(url).get().map(
        new Function<WSResponse, Pair<JsonNode,Integer>>() {
            public Pair<JsonNode,Integer> apply(WSResponse response) {
                Integer status=response.getStatus();
                JsonNode json = response.asJson();
                return new Pair(json,status);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thx! I gonna check it out asap.